# SQL regroup only chosen records

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 1 column with the number 0 called `product_attribute_id` and that one needs to group with `product_id` because it's 0 (something like if record is 0 then regroup with column name `product_id`)

I can't just do GROUP BY because my others records will be gone. It only needs to group when my `product_attribute_id` has a records `0` in it with my other table called `product_id`

```
SELECT 
    od.id_order_detail,
    od.id_order,
    od.product_id,
    od.product_attribute_id,
    od.product_name,
    (od.product_quantity) AS 'Total closed'
FROM
    ex.ps_order_detail od
WHERE
    od.product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
            p.id_product
        FROM
            ex.ps_product p
        WHERE
            p.id_manufacturer = '1') 
ORDER BY od.product_attribute_id , od.product_id DESC
```

[image]

My other records needs to stay only records with `0` needs to groep with other column

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!!!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your column alias is invalid standard SQL.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  It is unclear what you want for the combined rows for many of the columns.  Here is one guess:

```
SELECT MAX(od.id_order_detail) as id_order_detail,
       MAX(od.id_order) as id_order,
       (CASE WHEN product_attribute_id > 0 THEN product_attribute_id END) as product_attribute_id, 
       MAX(od.product_attribute_id) as product_attribute_id, 
       od.product_name,
       SUM(od.product_quantity) AS TotalClosed
FROM ex.ps_order_detail od
WHERE od.product_id IN (SELECT p.id_product
                        FROM ex.ps_product p
                        WHERE p.id_manufacturer = 1  -- ids are probably  not strings
                       ) 
GROUP BY product_id, product_name,
         (CASE WHEN product_attribute_id > 0 THEN product_attribute_id END)
ORDER BY product_attribute_id, product_id DESC;
```